# Using Nest Phrase Suggester on MultiSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, search-suggestion

I have a MultiSearch query over multiple types with multiple fields per type. I see that I can add a .SuggestPhrase() to an individual SearchDescriptor on an individual field, but not to an entire search query.  How can I apply a Phrase suggestion to a multisearch query?  Ideally it would be applied to all fields that are being searched on.

My use case is this: A user performs a MultiSearch query. They didn't find what they wanted.  At this point I'd like to suggest a different query that might be what they're looking for.  This would be similar to Google's "Did you mean..." recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggest example.

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "did-you-mean": {
      "text": "pizaz",
      "phrase": {
        "field": "your-field-that-has-the-phrases-to-suggest-to",
        "direct_generator": [
          {
            "field": "your-field-that-has-the-phrases-to-suggest-to",
            "suggest_mode": "always",
            "post_filter": "standard"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "did-you-mean-field2": {
      "text": "piza",
      "phrase": {
        "field": "your-field-that-has-the-phrases-to-suggest-to-field2",
        "direct_generator": [
          {
            "field": "your-field-that-has-the-phrases-to-suggest-to-field2",
            "suggest_mode": "always",
            "post_filter": "standard"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? It appears to be unrelated to a multisearch, and it also appears that I have to specify each field individually. In my case I'll have about 40 different fields.  I'm looking for a method that scales better.

Comment: You can just use the "_all" instead of a specific field. As far as I know you can't specify a list of fields such as "field": ["field1", "field2"] so this is the only way to segment on specific fields

Comment: @leavesof3 Just wondering if this is still the case that we can't specify the fields we want instead of doing "_all"?