# Is it possible to combine _msearch and a suggester in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, search-suggestion

I'm trying to bundle [multi search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) with a [term suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#search-suggesters).

When I try to use a suggester on the search endpoint, it works:

```json
POST my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "match": {
      "message": "tring out Elasticsearch"
    }
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggestion" : {
      "text" : "tring out Elasticsearch",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "message"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how to try to do the same with multi search:

```json
GET my-index-000001/_msearch
{ }
{
  "query" : {
    "match": {
      "message": "tring out Elasticsearch"
    }
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggestion" : {
      "text" : "tring out Elasticsearch",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "message"
      }
    }
  }
}
{"index": "my-index-000002"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
```

As a result, I get an error:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
        "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 2]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
    "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 2]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

So my question is, is it even possible?

I found a similarly named question ([Using Nest Phrase Suggester on MultiSearch query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732404/using-nest-phrase-suggester-on-multisearch-query)), but the question itself appears to be about [multi-match queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), not multi search.

The version I'm using is 7.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are syntactically correct but the Multi Search API (`_msearch`) only supports [newline-delimited json payloads](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search-api-desc) (`ndjson`).

As such, line breaks (`\n`) can only occur when separating the payload header from the payload body:

```json
header\n
body\n
header\n
body\n
...
```

So, adjust your line breaks to conform with the required structure:

```json
GET my-index-000001/_msearch
{}
{"query":{"match":{"message":"tring out Elasticsearch"}},"suggest":{"my-suggestion":{"text":"tring out Elasticsearch","term":{"field":"message"}}}}
{"index":"my-index-000002"}
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```

Tip: if you're using Kibana (and it looks like you are), you can toggle between the expanded and the _msearch-valid mode with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.